# Java: How to round up all of the elements in an array to two digits after decimal point?

Tags: java, arrays, double, decimal-point

I have a problem with rounding double values from an array.

When I started learning JAVA, I was surprised that the printing of arrays is different. What I mean is, in order to print out the whole array full of float values, you can't just loop (i) times and do `System.out.println("%.2f", array[i]);`.

The way to print it is `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));`

If it wasn't an array, I would round up the float just with `System.out.println("%.2f, val)` . However, with an array, I don't know how to do it. Appreciate the help.

Here is my whole class for calculating. Every calculation is correct and well, the only problem is rounding and printing.

```
package sample;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Calculations extends Data{

    public void calculateLinearCredit()
    {
        double[] linearCredit = new double[super.term];
        double[] linearInterest = new double [super.term];
        double[] linearPayment = new double [super.term];


        double firstMonthInterest = ((super.loan / super.term) * super.percentage) / 100;
        double Credit = super.loan / super.term;
        double interestDiff = firstMonthInterest/12;

        linearInterest[0] = firstMonthInterest;


        for(int i = 0; i < linearCredit.length; i++)
        {
            linearCredit[i] = Credit;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < linearInterest.length; i++)
        {
            linearInterest[i] = linearInterest[i-1] - interestDiff;
        }


        for(int i = 0; i < linearPayment.length; i++)
        {
            linearPayment[i] = linearInterest[i] + linearCredit[i];
        }

        //-----------------------------------------------
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linearPayment));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linearCredit));
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linearInterest));
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not an acronym

Comment: I know what an acronym is, but I don't understand the point you're trying to make. I suppose it's something to do with English not being my native tongue?

Comment: *you can't just loop (i) times and do System.out.println(array[i])*: of course you can.

Comment: Just picking on the spelling of Java in all-caps. But to answer your question, you just need a loop: `for (float val : array) System.out.println("%.2f", val);`

Comment: @JBNizet sorry - what I originally meant was I get errors once I do 
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            System.out.println("%.2f", linearPayment[i]);

Comment: *I get errors*: We can't help you with such a vague description of the problem. Post your code in your question, and post the exact and complete error(s) you get, still in your question.

Comment: *you can't just loop (i) times and do System.out.println("%.2f", array[i]);.* Well you can, but using `String.format`

Comment: *System.out.println("%.2f, val)* that does no rounding at all, it just trims string representation of float to 2 floating point places.

Comment: @rychiune I guess that shmosel is grammar natzi and he meant that it is Java not JAVA (like SOLID od KISS) as it is not created by first letters of some sort of name etc .]

Comment: updated my original post with my class. @shmosel when I write your suggestion, I get errors
    Error:(42, 23) java: no suitable method found for println(java.lang.String,double)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method java.io.PrintStream.println(boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
and some more, but I can't copy all of them due to character limit

Comment: @rychiune It is because you are using `println` not `printf`. Check my answer.

Comment: Try `printf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `Math.round()`

```
double[] array = new double[]{12.5698, 123.12345,0.1, 41234.212431324};    
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
     array[i] = Math.round(array[i] * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

> in order to print out the whole array full of float values, you
>   can't just loop (i) times and do System.out.println("%.2f", array[i]);

**You can** but using `System.out.format()`

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
    System.out.format("%.2f ",array[i]);

}

Output: 12.57 123.12 0.10 41234.21
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I see that this is a much better solution to my problem that the  whole ("%.2f",val). I have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> you can't just loop (i) times and do System.out.println("%.2f", array[i])

Of course you can. Just use the right method.

```
float[] array = new float[]{1.2f, 2.3425f, 3.4525f};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  System.out.printf("%.2f%n", array[i]);
}
```

You can even do:

```
for (float value : array) {
  System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value);
}
```

If you fancy the new `Stream` API you could also do this (you have to use `double` though for some intricate type system reasons I shouldn't go into here).

```
double[] dblArray = new double[]{1.2, 2.3425, 3.4525};
Arrays.stream(dblArray)
        .forEach(value -> System.out.printf("%.2f%n", value));
```